# Does a command like \sepstartrule exist in MusixTex?

Tags: musixtex

a MusixTex novice here. There are clearly defined commands `\sepbarrules` and `\nostartrule` in MusixTex. I would need separated rules at the `\startpiece`, not just at inner bar boundaries. Alternatively, an empty bar of zero width would do. Before I bury myself in the sources and try to help myself, I want to save time and ask others:  Is there anything like that readily available?

Thanks, Honza.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, just a quick and dirty hint... remedy to my burning problem... It would be nice to have a systemic solution...

I have placed the whole "piece" into a hbox like this:

```
\hbox{{\rlap{\vrule depth-14.8pt height 31.2pt width\lthick}%
  {\vrule depth-59.8pt height 76.2pt width\lthick}}\vbox{\startpiece
....here the stuff comes...
\zstoppiece}}
```

Most lengths can be determined from the vertical length parameters, given
in the chapter 'Layout Parameters' of the MusixTeX book. It did the trick, as the enclosed image shows (second group in the middle):

[image: "sepbarrules"]

Honza